# How to start auto scroll webpage on demand with a start stop button

Tags: javascript, animation, autoscroll

I am trying to get my script which autoscrolls my webpage to just start on demand on a start and stop button please can you help

```js
//run instantly and then goes after (setTimeout interval)

$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 50000);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 50000);
}, 50000);
setInterval(function() {
  // 50000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 50000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 50000);
  }, 50000);

}, 50000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code creates `scroll` JavaScript variable (as setInterval() function) and runs it. The function will *scroll a page every 2 sec* (2000 msec). You may adjust the auto scroll speed by changing this value. The single run down scroll height is defined by scrollBy()’s second parameter – 1000; a window will be scrolled down on 1000 px.

```js
function start_scroll_down() { 
   scroll = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0, 1000); console.log('start');}, 1500);
}

function stop_scroll_down() {
   clearInterval(scroll);
   console.log('stop');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="start_scroll_down();">Start Scroll</button>
<button onclick="stop_scroll_down();">Stop Scroll</button>
```